# Mobile profile site icons confused

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web

While looking at my profile on my iPhone with either Mobile Safari or Chrome for iOS my list of accounts is rendered thusly:

[image: mobile account list]

These icons are rather mixed up, don't you think? None of the icons used match the site they are displayed with; the only thing that is consistent is that the Super User Meta icon for Meta Stack Overflow at least matches the Super User icon used with Stack Overflow. This is probably a CSS sprite offset error.

This happens on *all* sites, and on other profiles besides mine. It is also platform and browser independent; [Generic reproduced this on Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212279/mobile-profile-site-icons-confused#comment683022_212279).

**Update**: Reproduced on Chrome on Mac (desktop browser), by clicking on the 'mobile' link in the footer (don't forget to switch back to 'full site'). This is indeed a sprite offset problem; the [CSS sprites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/skins/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=2770d9de73d16030232af54e656a82ba) look fine, the offsets are off by 4 icons:

[image: sprite detail]

Comment: Clearly the hats have gotten a hold of the icons.

Comment: So, the downvote means what, exactly? Nope, not a bug, or not enough info here, or cannot be reproduced, or should not get any priority, or what? Is there anything I should improve?

Comment: I can only assume it's for the *obvious* omission of freehand circles.

Comment: I'll have to add those in when not on mobile then... For now, consider the freehand circles to be in the same place as the missing *correct* icons.

Comment: Bug is also here on Android(4.2.1 gNexus stock browser), by the way. Not surprising, but figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirm; it probably would also be visible in a desktop browser, switched to the mobile theme via the link in footer.

Comment: reproduced fixing shortly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We launched some new sites and the mobile skin picked up the old (pre-launch) sprite file. Fixed in build rev `2013.12.18.1783` on meta and `2013.12.18.1247` on sites.

Since the cache breaker url hasn't changed, you'll need to either Ctrl+F5 or clear the browser cache to see the result.

Comment: Can't you add future site icons to the sprites? ;)

Comment: Confirmed fixed on the desktop. I'll leave my iPhone cache to expire on its own and put up with the wrong icons until that time.